# Performances - Better change the color of drawable or change drawable?

Tags: java, android, performance

I got a big list of elements to display. In each row I got some text in a TextView and an ImageView with a drawable set as background. Since I need to change the drawable (same shape but in a different color) for a lot of them and for other I want to keep the default drawable what I'm wondering is: in order to perform it the most efficient as possible this what's the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create a white drawable, then use a tint color on top of that.